# Unicode via ODBC

Tags: sql-server, r, unicode

I have created an ODBC connection to MS SQL Server, it work fine with normal data.

However, when the data contains "HKSCS" character, it will turn into `?`

Here is the table structure (simplified):

```
╔════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║      Column_name       ║   Type   ║
╠════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ TraditionalChineseName ║ nvarchar ║
║ EnglishName            ║ nvarchar ║
╚════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

ODBC Setting:

```
Odbc32.dll: 6.1.7601.23403
Driver: SQL Server Native Client 11.0
Option:
    Use ANSI quoted identifiers
    Use ANSI nulls, paddings and warnings
    Perform translation for character data
```

Sample data:

```
╔════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ TraditionalChineseName ║ EnglishName ║
╠════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 邨                     ║ estate      ║
║ 衞生                   ║ health      ║
╚════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Collation in SQL Server: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

The result work fine in both SSMS and .NET program (connect via SQL Server Driver), but not cannot work with ODBC connection.

Goal:
I want to pass the data to **R** and plot it.
However, when data stored in `data.frame`, those `HKSCS` character will become `?`.
Furthermore, if I plot it, all non-english character cannot display properly.

Question:
I tried to get the result and paste it in `R studio` and form it as `data.frame`, I found it can display properly, but it store the character in `<U+xxxx>` format.
I'm just wondering is it possible to change those characters into `<U+`, for example (`邨` to `<U+90A8>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trial, I have convert the string in SQL to "*unicode number*", and parse it in *R*

in short:

> "邨" -> "37032" -> "\u90A8" -> "< U+90A8>"

First, convert chinese character to hex based unicode number in SQL:

```
;with targetTable as (
    -- sim the table from database
    select 1 as ID, N'邨' as TraditionalChineseName, 'estate' as EnglishName union
    select 2 as ID, N'衞生' as TraditionalChineseName, 'health' as EnglishName
), ctx as (
    select top (8000) n = row_number() over (order by Number)
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values order by Number
), tc as (
    -- convert character to unicode (dec) then binary (hex, 0x12345678)
    -- get the last 4 digit
    select f.ID, '\u' + right(convert(varchar(10), convert(varbinary(4), unicode(substring(f.TraditionalChineseName, x.n, 1))), 2), 4) as unicodeStr, 
    substring(f.TraditionalChineseName, x.n, 1) as charStr, x.n
    from ctx x
    inner join targetTable f with (nolock)
        on x.n <= len(f.TraditionalChineseName)
)
select distinct s.ID, s.EnglishName,
            (
                select u1.unicodeStr as [text()]
                from tc u1
                where u1.ID = s.ID
                order by u1.n
                for xml path('')
            ) TraditionalChineseName
from targetTable s (nolock)
```

It will return a `dataset` like this

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+
| ID | EnglishName | TraditionalChineseName |
+----+-------------+------------------------+
|  1 | estate      | \u90A8                 |
|  2 | health      | \u885E\u751F           |
+----+-------------+------------------------+
```

In R, use `SqlQuery` to retrieve result set

```
library(RODBC)
myconn <- odbcConnect(dsn="ODBC", uid="...", pwd="...")
dat <- sqlQuery(channel = myconn, query = qry, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
close(myconn)
```

Create a function to convert each "character" back to unicode

```
convertUnicode <- function(x) {
  parse(text = paste0("'", x, "'"))[[1]]
}
```

Form a new `data.frame`

```
kvp <- data.frame(ID = dat$ID, 
                  TraditionalChineseName = unlist(lapply(dat$TraditionalChineseName, convertUnicode)), 
                  EnglishName = dat$EnglishName)
```

With this method, the character can be displayed in any chart or table, and do not need to modify the locale setting in R